# Are the keywords 'wire' & 'reg' used correctly?

Tags: verilog

This is the program that I have problems with. I think its the `wire` and `reg` statements.
This was given in one of my books, but there seems to be some problem in the code

```
module dff (q, d, clk);
input d, clk ; 
output q ;
always @ (posedge clk) 
q = d ; 
endmodule
module shift4 (d_out, din, clk) ;
input din, clk ;
output d_out ; 
wire wO, wl, w2 ; 
reg wO, wl, w2, d_out ; 
dff go (wO, d in, clk) ; 
dff g1 (wl, wO, clk) ; 
dff g2 (w2, w1, clk) ; 
dff g3 (d out, w2, clk) ;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not declare wO, wl, w2 as both `wire` and `reg`.   Just use `wire`.

Also, you should use nonblocking assignments for sequential logic:

```
q <= d;
```

Answer (score 0):

q should be a reg, since you change it in an always block.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the more modern syntax from Verilog 1364-2001. it would be much clearer in that you only have declare each signal once, not up to 3 times.

```
module shift4 (output reg  d_out, 
               input  wire din, clk);
  // internal signals
  wire wO, wl, w2 ; 
  dff go (wO, d in, clk) ; 
  dff g1 (wl, wO, clk) ; 
  dff g2 (w2, w1, clk) ; 
  dff g3 (d out, w2, clk) ;
endmodule
```